# ASP.NET obtener el certificado digital desde navegador del cliente

Tags: c#, asp.net, aeat-sii

Estoy realizando un enlace con la AEAT para el tema del SII.
Tengo un problema con la lectura del certificado. Me he encontrado que si tengo el certificado instalado en el nevagador, en producción, funciona correctamente, pero al publicar el proyecto no encuentra el certificado. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar para saber como obtener el certificado desde el navegador del cliente?

Os dejo el código que estoy utilizando actualmente.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.
Un saludo.

```
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, toreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, NS_CERTIFICADO, true);
    if (certificates.Count == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("NOT FOUND: {0}", NS_CERTIFICADO));
    X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];
    webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
```

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo en ese código es recuperar el certificado que esté instalado en el ordenador local pero no el del cliente. Necesitas usar tu propio certificado o el certificado del cliente?

Comment: Hola miguel, gracias, necesito utilizar el certificado del cliente para presentar el fichero xml a la aeat. Necesito usar su certificado, instalado en el navegador para poder presentar ese xml. No se si me explico. Lo busco por su número de serie.

Comment: Entonces si no me equivoco deberás sacar el certificado del cliente del HttpRequest,además tendrás que habilitar SSl  en tu servidor si no me equivoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os dejo como he conseguido solucionarlo por si a alguien le sirve.

```
string certificadoURL = @"c:\certificados\certificado.pfx";
string certificadoPASS = "password";
X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2(certificadoURL, certificadoPASS, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
return webRequest;
```

Comment: Pero así estás obteniendo el certificado que esté en el servidor y no en el cliente no? @Perku

Comment: Deberías obtener el certificado como bien te dijeron en un comentario anterior, a partir del request. Verifica este enlace [Propiedad HttpRequest.ClientCertificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httprequest.clientcertificate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No tengo que utilizar el certificado del SSL, necesito utilizar un certificado digital del cliente para presentar documentos a la administración. He probado con el ClientCertificate y me selecciona el certificado del SSL del servidor. Creo que no formulé bien la pregunta o no entiendo como trabajar con certificados.